# merge two pdf side by side with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have 2 pdf with 10x130in and 10x140in (both single page), I use below code to merge it side by side but it doesn't work!

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                 
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                                                       
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}                                                                                            
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                                                                                   
\begin{document}                                                                                                        
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                       
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east] (A) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{A.pdf}};                  
    \node[inner sep=0pt,right=0 of A,anchor=north west] (b) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{B.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                       
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to remove `anchor=north west`...

Comment: ...Or use `at={(A.north east)},anchor=north west` instead of `right=0 of A,anchor=north west`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Positioning` options like `right=0 of A` determine two anchors, an anchor on `A` and another one on the node you want to position. In case of `right`, it will place `B.west` at `A.east`. When you say `anchor=north west`, `TikZ` will place `B.north west` at `A.east`.

If you want, both figures aligned on top, you should use `below right=0 of A.north east`. This way `B.north west` (selected by `below right`) will be placed at `A.north east`.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                 
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                                                       
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}                                                                                            
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                                                                                   
\begin{document}                                                                                                        
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                       
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east] (A) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height=4cm]{example-image-A}};                  
    \node[inner sep=0pt,below right=0 of A.north east] (b) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height=3cm]{example-image-B}};
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                       
\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case, you don't need to use `TikZ` for this composition, `adjustbox` package can do it.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}                                                                                                        

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height=4cm, valign=t]{example-image-A}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the trick ! I did not know that \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} exports the keys of \adjustbox to \includegraphics. Extremely useful !